# R: Running Models on Datasets From Global Environment

Tags: r, loops

I am working with the R programming language.

I have many datasets in the Global Environment with similar names:

```
test_data = data.frame( class = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)), var1 = rnorm(100,100,100), var2 = rnorm(100,100,100), var_3 = rnorm(100,100,100)) 

train_data_1 = data.frame( class = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)), var1 = rnorm(100,100,100), var2 = rnorm(100,100,100), var_3 = rnorm(100,100,100)) 

train_data_2 = data.frame( class = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)), var1 = rnorm(100,100,100), var2 = rnorm(100,100,100), var_3 = rnorm(100,100,100)) 

train_data_3 = data.frame( class = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)), var1 = rnorm(100,100,100), var2 = rnorm(100,100,100), var_3 = rnorm(100,100,100)) 

train_data_4 = data.frame( class = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)), var1 = rnorm(100,100,100), var2 = rnorm(100,100,100), var_3 = rnorm(100,100,100)) 

train_data_5 = data.frame( class = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)), var1 = rnorm(100,100,100), var2 = rnorm(100,100,100), var_3 = rnorm(100,100,100))
```

I want to run a model on each of these datasets at the same time using a loop:

```
library(randomForest)
    
      results <- list()
results2 <- list()

for (i in 1:100)

{

    rf_i <- randomForest(class~., data=train_data_i)
predict_i <- predict(rf_i , test_data ,type="prob")

    results[[i]] <- rf_i

results2[[i]] <- predict_i

}

    #I am not sure how to add this part into the loop - currently doing this manually

    final_predictions_class_0 = (predict_1[,1] + predict_2[,1] + predict_3[,1] + predict_4[,1] + predict_5[,1])/5
    final_predictions_class_1 = (predict_1[,2] + predict_2[,2]  + predict_3[,2] +  predict_4[,2] +  predict_5[,2])/5
final_data = data.frame(final_predictions_class_0, final_predictions_class_1)
```

But this returns an error: `Error in eval(m$data, parent.frame()) : object 'train_data_i' not found`

I find this strange because I am able to run each line individually (e.g.     `rf_1 <- randomForest(class~., data=train_data_1),  rf_2 <- randomForest(class~., data=train_data_2) .... predict_1 <- predict(rf_1 , test_data ,type="prob"),  predict_2 <- predict(rf_2 , test_data ,type="prob") ....`)

But I can't seem to figure out how to run everything in a loop and create the "final_data" file.

**Can someone please show me how to fix this problem?**

Comment: just grab all the data in a list and loop over the list. ie `mget(ls(pattern = 'train_data'))`

Comment: Your training datasets exist as “independent” objects, rather than in a list or array. You cannot loop over them as you are attempting to do. R does not know - and cannot know - that you want the `i` in `train_data_i` To be taken as a “suffix”. @onyambu has given you a solution. Alternatively, iterate over a list of training datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your loop as follows:

```
for (i in 1:100)
{
   data_to_use <- get(paste0('train_data', i))
    results[[i]] <- randomForest(class~., data=data_to_use)
    results2[[i]] <- predict(results[[i]] , test_data ,type="prob")
}
```

Note that this is not the correct way to approach the problem though it solves the issue at hand. The best way is to get everything into a list then loop though the list. ie:

```
my_data_list <- mget(ls(pattern = 'train_data'))
for (i in seq_along(my_data_list))
{
   data_to_use <- my_data_list[[i]]
    results[[i]] <- randomForest(class~., data=data_to_use)
    results2[[i]] <- predict(results[[i]] , test_data ,type="prob")
}
```

Using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
mget(ls(pattern = 'train_data')) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = 'grp') %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise(result = list(randomForest::randomForest(class~., cur_data()))) %>%
  mutate(predict = map(result, predict, type = 'prob'))
```